# jquery sum all values in repeating row array

Tags: jquery

Hello everyone I couldn't find the solution for ;

```
<tr><td> Some Code here <input name="forwardings[nodes][amount][]" class="repeatingClass"> some more code here </td> </tr>
<tr><td> Some Code here <input name="forwardings[nodes][amount][]" class="repeatingClass"> some more code here </td> </tr>
<tr><td> Some Code here <input name="forwardings[nodes][amount][]" class="repeatingClass"> some more code here </td> </tr>
```

and I need to sum all repeatingClass values when I focus out from one of these I tried something like this but couldn't handle this;

```
 $('.repeatingClass').focusout(function(){
     var totalPoints = 0;
   $('.repeatingClass').each(function(){
     totalPoints += $('.repeatingClass').val();
   });
   alert(totalPoints);
 });
```

What can I do ?
regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The empty values in your inputs are being interpreted as strings. So you should check to see first if there is a value, and if so, add it to the total after calling `parseInt` or `parseFloat`

```
$(function(){

     $('.repeatingClass').focusout(function(){
         var totalPoints = 0;

       $('.repeatingClass').each(function(){

           if ($(this).val())
               totalPoints += parseInt($(this).val());
       });

       alert(totalPoints);

     });

});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/tjj6b8dv/) is a fiddle